How to create and apply conditional/nested middleware in Nestjs?

suppose we have 3 middlewares:

export function logger(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  console.log(`Request...`);
  if (req.something) {
     logger2(req,res, next);
  } else {
     logger3(req,res, next);
  }
};
export function logger2(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  console.log(`Request...`);
  next();
};
export function logger3(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  console.log(`Request...`);
  next();
};


How can achieve this if I want to write the logger in class basic style:

import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class LoggerMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    console.log('Request...');
    next();
  }
}


conditionally call logger2 / logger3  middleware in the LoggerMiddleware
